# Are HTML files cached?

Tags: build, gruntjs

I am working on grunt build task that automatically renames files for cache busting. I am doing that for CSS and JS files but was wondering if i need to cache bust HTML files well.  I am not sure if HTML files are cached by browsers or any of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply embed cache control tags in the HTML header to prevent that page for being cached:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-control" content="no-store" />
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're doing things properly you're serving HTML By **gzippe**d anyway(Assuming that you have enabled Gzip for HTML), so the low-hanging fruit of HTML minification - whitespace - isn't all that relevant. There aren't lots of easy targets (e.g. variable names) for minification in HTML, which are present in CSS and JavaScript. Much of the content of HTML is the actual content of the page, which probably can't be minified (and, as others have pointed out, will almost certainly vary more frequently than your CSS or JS).

But again No harm on minification of HTMl anyways. The point is..option of gzipping HTML probably eliminates much of the need to minify anyway.